# Deleting Specific Index on VueJS2

Tags: vuejs2

I am using the following code:

```
removeElement (index) {
this.books.splice(index, 1);
}
```

Element Books:

```
books: [
        {
          name: 'Hamlet',
          author: 'William Shakespeare',
          date: '1609',
          language: 'English'
        },
        {
          name: 'A Boys Will',
          author: 'Robert Frost',
          date: '1913',
          language: 'English'
        }
      ]
```

It is working but it is removing index 0 everytime.
How to fix this issue? I am using VueJS 2.

Comment: there should not be any problem with the code, the problem probably is with the index being passed to the function

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
removeElement (index) {
    var books = this.books
    var filteredBooks = books.filter(function(book, i) {
        return index !== i
    })
    this.books = filteredBooks
}
```